# How to select row if not registered at many to many table

Tags: php, mysql, database, many-to-many

i have 3 tables:

**student**

```
id, name
1, Max
2, Brian
```

**class**

```
id, code, type
1, AIF102, Lab
2, AIF102, Class
3, AIF104, Class
```

**student_class**

```
student_id, class_id
1, 1
```

How can i select the code row where the student with the code not registered at student_class. Ie, Just select code AIF104 where the student is Max. Select code AIF102 and AIF104 where the student is Brian. Sorry for bad english, Thx before.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is a bit hard to follow. Did you want to select the students that do not appear in `student_class`?

Comment: i want to select the code class(es) where the student is an input that have not registered at student_class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use left join with is null to get the courses in which a particular student is not registered

```
select c.*
from class c
left join student_class sc on(c.id = sc.class_id )
left join student s on (s.id = sc.student_id and s.id = 1 )
where  c.`type` = 'Class'
and sc.student_id  is null
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/023f0/2)

another attempt for same name of course

```
select c.*
from class c
where not exists (
  select c1.code
  from class c1
  left join student_class sc on(c1.id = sc.class_id )
  where  sc.student_id  = 1
  and c1.code = c.code
)
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac75d8/13)

Comment: Thx mate, but my code row have mutiple same values, ie: 1, AIF102, Lab and 2, AIF102, class. In your demo, the code row is unique. I just want to select the code that never registered to student x. I just dont care about type class, if in student_class table have registered id that bind code AIF102, i dont want to select it again.

Comment: @BandiSu i have added another query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM student S, class C, student_class SC WHERE
S.id = SC.student_id AND SC.class_id = C.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join all the tables together. As long as you explicitly state the relationship you should be able to get the records you need. Just add your own `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT s.name, c.code, c.type
FROM class c
     INNER JOIN student_class sc ON c.id = sc.class_id
     INNER JOIN student s ON s.id = sc.student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code,name,type 
FROM class c, student s, student_class sc
where (c.class_id!=sc.class_id) OR (s.student_id !=sc.student_id) 
order by name,code;

OUTPUT of the above query is below here..

code  |name |type
__________________
AIF102|Brian|Class
AIF102|Brian|Lab
AIF104|Brian|Class
AIF102|Max  |Class
AIF104|Max  |Class
```